# Numeric labels missing in formatted bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, acm

I have an error with the ACM style files (no others - yet) in that the numeric labels -- `[1]`, `[2]`, etc -- in the bibliography are missing.

They appear in the text but the formatted entries in the bibliography, while sorted alphabetically, are missing the numeric labels.

I've created a simple `test.tex` (attached) and the output (also attached).

With `article` and `llncs` style it works fine.

```
\documentclass{sigkddExp}
\def\newblock{}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{document}
\title{A Taxonomy for Temporal Frequent Pattern Mining} 
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\section*{Abstract}
Blah blah.  \cite{AASY97}

\bibliography{../../JFR}   
\end{document}
```

====

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: For the record, I can confirm that [sigkddExp](http://www.kdd.org/formats/sigkddExp.cls) **does** number the references (`\list{[\arabic{enumi}]}{% ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sigkddExp` document class -- I found the class file online at `http://www.kdd.org/formats/sigkddExp.cls` -- contains the following instruction at line 1180:

```
\let\@biblabel\@gobble
```

It doesn't take too much imagination to guess what this instruction achieves: It "gobbles" the numeric label at the start of each formatted entry. That's exactly the issue you've come across.

How to proceed? If you're forced to use the `sigkddExp` document class, don't do anything, except maybe report the issue to an editor. However, since this document class has persisted unchanged since 1999 (according to the file's header) I wouldn't hold out much hope that anybody in charge will see fit to make a substantive change to the file.

If you think you can get away with a slight modification to the document class file, I suggest you begin by making a copy of `sigkddExp.cls`; call the new version `sigkddExp-bib.cls`, say. Next, open `sigkddExp-bib.cls` in a text editor, jump to line 1180, and comment out the `\let\@biblabel\@gobble` instruction. Insert a comment somewhere nearby to note that you made a change. If you're a stickler for details (which may well be the case, given that you've posted a query about this issue to this site...), do also provide a paragraph in the file's header to note the date and content of the change you made. This note could be something as simple as

```
2017/08/21: Commented out the instruction "\let\@biblabel\@gobble"
```

Finally, change the `\documentclass` instruction to

```
\documentclass{sigkddExp-bib}
```

and recompile your document.

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{abc,author="Anne B. Cuthor", title="Thoughts", year=3001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{sigkddExp-bib} % modified cls file is in use
\def\newblock{}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}
Blah blah. \cite{abc}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I couldn't imagine the numbering would be gobbled. Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Just put this

`\renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@[{\arabic{enumiv}}]}`

in:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@[{\arabic{enumiv}}]}
\bibitem{Review}James Franco.

\bibitem{Corden}James Corden.

\end{thebibliography}
```

And this is the Output:

[image: Output]

After the @ sign in that line, just put anything to be the label.